# how python print me each element when i use random?

Tags: python-2.7, list, random, element

I need a list of 8 elements and i want that python randomly import that elements in a list. But i need each of them elements in a list. Like this:

I need numbers of 0 to 4 in a list, but if I write:

```
s = []
for i in range(8):
    s.append(random.randint(0,4))
print("s:", s)
```

python doesn't print me each of number at least once. Python print me like that:

`s = [1,0,2,2,1,0,1,3]`- in this list is 4 missing but i want all 5 numbers at least once in a list.

Please help me.

Comment: Your code is *random*. You could get get no fours, or only fours, or anywhere in-between. *"i want all 5 numbers at least once in a list"* - but that's not what you've written. Is that the only constraint?

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i need a random list(8) of elements from 0 to 4 where will be each number at least once in a list.

Comment: I have a homework:

Write a program, that will randomly create a list of sharing 5 photos (lenght 8) and each photo must be shared at least once.

Comment: And why should someone else write your homework?

Comment: This is just one example from many, but I tried like You can see and I didn't do a big mistake, just forgot some things. That's why i ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a list of eight items, consisting of at least one each of the elements 0,1,2,3,4, then what you really want is a list of [0,1,2,3,4] and three additional random elements, all in random order:

```
import random

# start a list with one each of the desired elements
s = [0,1,2,3,4]

# add three more elements
for i in range(3):
    s.append(random.randint(0,4))
    # randomize the order of the elements in the list
    random.shuffle(s)
print("s:", s)
```

Comment: That's what i wanted.. Thank you so much!